# Why does the "Ask Question" page have an "Ask Question" button?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

When writing a question, why is there an "Ask Question" button? It always confuses me when I submit a question.

Maybe hide it? Or replace it with "Post Question"?

Comment: The "ask question" button is disabled in the "ask question" page.

Comment: How would replacing it with "Post Question" make it any less confusing?

Comment: It's consistent with the rest of the UI, all the "buttons" on that row are displayed and highlighted when you're in that navigation area.

Comment: It did confuse to me, so I wrote.

Comment: If you really want to, you could write a userscript / userstyle

Answer (score 1):

> It always confuses me when I submit a question.

Just try to remember that, you have already clicked "Submit a question" and you are surrounded by questiony things. Such as a form input area to put in the title/subject, under that you have similar question suggestions, then a large textarea to type out your question, then the preview text of whatever you have current typed for your question, then a form area to select tags, with relevant text informing about question tags.
Then lastly you have a button stating ""Post Your Question" at the bottom.

Normally where all this is you would see an actual question someone has already posted and comments and answers, and instead of "Post Your Question" you would see a text area to type an *answer* and a button "Post your *Answer*".

Then on the right you have a lot of helpful information all relevant to asking a question only, and the usual links to other already posted questions related to the current one you are viewing are gone.

The browser you are viewing has "Ask a question" in the top of your browser and the tab you are viewing.

All this is showing you are currently in the "ask a question" are and not "view a question".

Also, don't forget, the "Ask A Question" button is greyed out and no longer click-able.

Don't worry, once you have been here a little longer all the things I've outlined above will be more familiar to you and you will be able to see at a glance where you are. You'll have a clearer understanding of all things Stack.
Any new site, whether a forum, Q&A site, blog etc, often has differences to other sites and takes a little getting used to.